# C# String Length for Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics

I developing a program like Word. For that I need to write strings into the same "line", and I also want the ability to format each word/letter/sentence differently, controlling color, size, font, etc.

So I have to calculate the pixel length and height of a string, to put them into a line. But there is a problem with the function `(Graphics) MeasureString`, this function puts extra length infront/behind a string. This function has also has some problems with white space.

I tried a different StringFormater, but everytime they return too much length or not enough.

Does a function exist to write different formated strings on the `Graphics` object or a function to calculate the exact pixel length of a string?

Comment: Look at the methods "remarks" @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx  - it explains about the extra spacing (overhanging glyphs) & notes that `MeasureCharacterRanges` is what to use for precise layout calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this is a fairly tricky problem to solve properly - you may be better off trying to find an existing control (e.g. the [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox)) that solves this for you.

That said if you do want to do this then this is more-or-less the correct way to solve this problem, however if you take a look at the [MeasureString documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring) you will note that the behaviour you are seeing is intentional

> The [MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring) method is designed for use with individual strings
> and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string
> to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the [DrawString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) method adjusts
> glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string
> narrower than reported by **MeasureString**. To obtain metrics suitable
> for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing
> formatted text), use the [MeasureCharacterRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges) method or one of the
> MeasureString methods that takes a [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat), and pass
> [GenericTypographic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.generictypographic). Also, ensure the [TextRenderingHint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint) for the
> [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics) is [AntiAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.textrenderinghint).

So it sounds to me like you should instead be using the [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead.

Here is a sample I prepared that deals renders some text in two different colours. To try it out just paste it into a new form

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // This is where we wish to print our string
    var region = new RectangleF(50, 50, 200, 50);

    // This is the font we wish to use
    var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16.0F);

    // Draw a string for comparison
    DrawString(e.Graphics, "RedBlack", font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(50, 150, 200, 50));

    // Draw the first string and keep a track of the Region it was rendered in
    var first = DrawString(e.Graphics, "Red", font, Brushes.Red, region);

    // Adjust the region we wish to print 
    region = new RectangleF(region.X + first.GetBounds(e.Graphics).Width, region.Y, region.Width, region.Height);

    // Draw the second string
    DrawString(e.Graphics, "Black", font, Brushes.Black, region);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}

private Region DrawString(Graphics g, string s, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF layoutRectangle)
{
    var format = new StringFormat();
    format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new[] { new CharacterRange(0, s.Length) });

    g.DrawString(s, font, brush, layoutRectangle, format);
    return g.MeasureCharacterRanges(s, font, layoutRectangle, format)[0];
}
```

This is what it looks like

[image: screenshot of form]

Note that you need to be careful with clipping - GDI will "wrap" rendered text onto new lines for you by default, however this wont work any more, you will end up with something like this

[image: screenshot of form with incorrect line wrapping]

Also if you try and print out text with different fonts / font sizes then the "bottom" of each of those fonts won't line up where you expect it to.  Try taking a look at [Formatting text on a common baseline](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045800/http://bobpowell.net/formattingtext.aspx) for some hints on how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

MeasureString is defently the right way for solving this problem.
take a look at the sample at the bottom of this side http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/957webty(v=vs.80).aspx because I would say there isn t any other way.